# Jenkins Play! Plugin: Failure to configure auto-install on Cloudbees server

Tags: plugins, jenkins, playframework, cloudbees

I have installed the Jenkins plugin for the Play! framework: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/play-plugin

However, I run into a problem configuring that plugin. The Jenkins server doesn't have Play installed, so I tried to configure the auto-install, using the "Install automatically" option. Unfortunately, when I pass the URL to the Typesafe Activator's ZIP archive, I get a handshake failure.

The Jenkins server is a part of the Cloudbees cloud.

Any ideas on what is going wrong and how to deal with it?

[image: Please see the attached screenshot]

EDIT: Changing "https" to "http" resolves the handshake problem. However, Play does not get installed on the Jenkins server. The build does not find the "activator" executable. I suspect this may be an issue with the Play plugin for Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your java cacerts is not having correct certificate. you may try following steps.

Step 1 : Get root certificate of https://www.google.com

1. Open https://www.google.com in a chrome browser.
2. Select Inspect from context menu(right clicking on page) and navigate to security tab
3. Click on view certificates
4. Click on top most certificate on hierarchy and confirm it is tailed with Root CA phrase.
5. drag and drop that image which you saw written certificate on desktop.

Thats it! you got your root certificate!

Step 2 : install certificate to your java cacerts

please verify you have system variable JAVA_HOME declared and you will perform these steps on that jre cacerts only!

1. Navigate to cacerts by JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
2. Download and install keytool explorer it is available for all platforms
3. open cacerts in that tool and import cetificate by "import trusted certificate" button.
4. Save your changes (you may come across issue if it is mac and you do not have write access!)

Step 3 : Restart jenkins

You should not get ssl handshake problem now onwards.